# JAAS ticketcache without using a file location

Tags: java, kerberos, jaas

In JAAS, the ticketcache is specified using a filename. Can it be a some bytes in memory ?
eg instead of `ticketcache=c:\somewheremy_tgt_is`,  its `ticketcache=some_byte_array`

I asked because I already have the ticket in memory and I don't want to convert it into a file before passing it to JAAS login module.

thanks

Comment: Well atleast when it comes to windows if you do not specify KRB5CCNAME or ticketcache= option and just use useTicketCache, the ticket is picked up from in memory buffer called LSA. I know its not exactly what you want but I think that is the closest we can get.

Comment: Btw I am curious to know how you got the ticket in memory? Did you use LoginModule's internal classes? Typically ticket fetching is transparent if you use LoginContext login()